# Different values of time difference in Jasper Studio and JasperServer

Tags: jasper-reports

In my report created in Jasper Studio, I am calculating time difference between start time and end time in (Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds). It is showing correct value when I view the report in Jasper Studio.

But when I publish this report on JasperServer, only Days value is showing incorrect value. Like in Jasper Studio, it is showing 2 Days which is correct. But in JasperServer after publish, it is showing 61 Days!

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you give to us an example how looks like your calculation function?

Comment: In my database, date value is getting stored in this format 2017-05-10 12:17:02.000. I am using the following expression in jasperstudio to calculate number of days between two days: DAYS(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(LEFT( $V{v_start_time}, 19))),new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(LEFT( $F{end_time}, 19)))). Using LEFT function, I am just taking the first 19 digits of the date value stored in the database (ignoring .000).

Comment: Are you using the same Java settings in Jaspersoft Studio and on the server?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: As a possible solution in jasperserver you can use ElapsedDays(DATE_ENTERED, DATE_START) ElapsedMinutes(DATE_ENTERED, DATE_START) and etc. You can find these function when you are creating a calculation field.

Comment: Can you create a similar report on a sample database, for example foodmart or sugarcrm (these databases should be installed as default for Jasper Server). I suppose it can be a bug. If we can see the JRXML maybe it can help me to understand more.

Comment: When I checked the java version on the machine on which I am using Jasperstudio, it is 1.8.0_131. Java was already present in the machine before I installed Jasperstudio. When I ran the same report on another machine's jasperstudio on which java is not installed, it was also giving the wrong value of Days field (same incorrect values as on jasperserver). But even after installing java of same version in that machine, setting path and restarting it, it was still giving issue even in Jasperstudio. What can be the reason for this? Kindly suggest some solution for this.

Comment: Even after installation of the same java version which is working on my laptop on the other machine where jasperstudio is installed, it is not giving the desired results even in jasperstudio.

Comment: As I know Jasperserver does not support Java 1.8. You can try 1.7